# Android Studio cannot find Android Box on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging

I have an android box (Not a phone) and I need to connect it to Android Studio on my Mac. I can successfully connect a Motorola phone, but not this box.

About the device:

- It is running Android 4.4.2
- It is from a brand called Ghia
- It is running a custom launcher
- The device does not have a micro-usb port, but a USB-A instead, and I'm connecting it to my computer with a USB-A to USB-A cable

And yes, I have tried all the following:

- Making sure developer options are enabled
- Making sure USB Debugging is enabled
- It is connected to WiFi
- I have reset the device to factory settings

Is there anything that I can do to connect it to Android Studio and debug it?

Comment: Connect the device to computer and restart Android Studio by using `File - Invalidate Cache & Restart - Just Restart` (in Android Studio).

Comment: @Shashanth Nope, still nothing

Comment: Does `adb` from the command line find/not find it. Also if the android box has multiple USB ports, have you tried each of them.

Comment: @MorrisonChang It finds my Motorola phone but not the Android box while doing adb, and I tried switching usb ports but nothing still :(

Comment: And just to make sure the cable works, does the Android box mount? Can you copy files over via the USB A to A cable via Android File Transfer or as a external drive.